# How to moves the minimum value of the list to be the first element while preserving the order of the elements

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

if I have ArrayList of [5,9,4,2,8,12] how can i get output as [2,5,9,4,8,12]. I could find the minimum but I cannot get the above output.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> minToFront(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int first = list.get(0);
    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (list.get(i) < min) {

            min = list.get(i);
        }

        list.set(0, min);

    }

    return list;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to sort your ArrayList. Though there are more efficient ways to do this, let's start by fixing your method, `minToFront()`.

Using a similar approach, we can store a "default" value of the `min` and `minInd` (minimum index) to be the first value in our list:

```
int min = list.get(0);
int minInd = 0;
```

Next, we can iterate through our list and find the minimum element. We do this by finding elements smaller than `min`, and if we find an element that is smaller, then we redefine the values of `min` and `minInd`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

    if (list.get(i) < min) {
        minInd = i;
        min = list.get(i);
    }

}
```

Now that we know what the minimum element of the list is, we need to swap that value with our first element. We do this by creating a temporary variable that stores our first element, then swap:

```
int temp = list.set(0, min);
list.set(minInd,temp);

return list;
```

In our main method, we can sort the whole list by first defining another list that will store our sorted list.

While our old list still has elements, we can find the minimum element in our old list, move it to our new list, delete it from our old list, and then repeat this process until we have moved all our elements to our new list:

```
while(origList.size() > 0){
  origList = minToFront(origList);
  sortedList.add(origList.get(0));
  origList.remove(0);
}
```

After applying all these changes, our code should look something like this:

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> origList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    origList.add(5);
    origList.add(9);
    origList.add(4);
    origList.add(2);
    origList.add(8);
    origList.add(12);
    while(origList.size() > 0){
      origList = minToFront(origList);
      sortedList.add(origList.get(0));
      origList.remove(0);
    }
    System.out.println(sortedList);
  }
  public static ArrayList<Integer> minToFront(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int min = list.get(0);
    int minInd = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        if (list.get(i) < min) {
            minInd = i;
            min = list.get(i);
        }

    }
    int temp = list.get(0);
    list.set(0, min);
    list.set(minInd,temp);

    return list;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12]
```

I hope this answered your question! Please let me know if you need any further clarification or details :)

Comment: `List.set` returns the element previously at the specified position. Thus you can just do `int temp = list.set(0, min);`

Comment: I completely forgot about that, thank you for telling me haha. I will edit my answer

Comment: I wanted to implement OP's original method into my solution, but I agree that using a built-in sort method is easier

Comment: The post asks how to get from `[5,9,4,2,8,12]` to `[2,5,9,4,8,12]`, which is sorting. OP said that they were able to find minimum but could not sort the list

Comment: ...I am so stupid T_T i literally just looked at the first two and last two and was like "oh yeah thats sorted" dslgkfjbjlfds i mean i guess i still answered the question, but yeah thanks for telling me

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Main {    
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    int [] arr = new int [] {5,9,4,2,8,12};
    int[] arr2 = new int[arr.length];
    int index = 0;
    
    for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]<arr[i-1])
        {
            index=i;
        }
    }
    
    arr2[0]=arr[index];
    int counter=1;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        if(index!=i)
        {
            arr2[counter++]=arr[i];
        }
    }
      
    System.out.println();    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {     
        System.out.print(arr2[i] + " ");    
    }    
}
```

}

Comment: Please don't post a wall of code with no accompanying prose to explain

Answer (score -1):

````
    int minIndex = -1;
    int tmp = array[0];
    int min = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < min) {
            minIndex = i;
            min = array[i];
        }
    }
    array[0] = min;
    array[minIndex] = tmp;
    return array;
}```
````

Comment: Please don't post a wall of code with no accompanying prose to explain

Comment: Array will be more efficient as ArrayList() uses Array internally also it provide us the more control over the datastructure. Hence swapping the min index and 0th position value logic is written using array instead of collections